# Can I get some assistance with this C style string in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand un-managed code. I come from a background of C# and I'm playing around a little with C++.

Why is that this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[] = "sizeme";

    cout << sizeof(s);

    int i = 0;
    while(i<sizeof(s))
    {
        cout<<"\nindex "<<i<<":"<<s[i];
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

prints out this:

```
7
index 0:s
index 1:i
index 2:z
index 3:e
index 4:m
index 5:e
index 6:
```

????

Shouldn't sizeof() return 6?

Comment: +1 for an exceptionally well written and formatted question, even if it's simple and you might've been able to find the answer searching. If everyone who posted newbie questions did it this well it wouldn't be frustrating to see duplicates all the time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[C strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string) are "nul-terminated" which means there is an additional byte with value `0x00` at the end. When you call `sizeof(s)`, you are getting the size of the entire buffer *including* the nul terminator. When you call `strlen(s)`, you are getting the *length* of the string contained in the buffer, not including the nul.

Note that if you modify the contents of `s` and put a nul terminator somewhere other than at the end, then `sizeof(s)` would still be 7 (because that's a static property of how `s` is declared) but `strlen(s)` could be somewhat less (because that's calculated at runtime).

Answer (score 3):

No, all trings in C are terminated by the null character (ascii 0). So `s` is actually 7 bytes

```
s i z e m e \0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact, that C-strings contain the value `0` (or `'\0'`) as last character to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

s is seven bytes, 6 for the string and one for the null termination.